# How to create a \Zend\Form\Form object for a subset of Model properties?

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a model with say 10 properties for which I specify input filter rules for each.  I want to create a `\Zend\Form\Form` object which should only be for a subset of those 10 fields (say 5 of them).  The issue I am running into is that when I execute `\Zend\Form\Form::bind()` the input filter rules for all 10 fields are pulled in and since the form doesn't have 5 of them the validation comes up false (although zero error messages since the form doesn't have them).

I'm aware of a few options to get around this, but I'd like to maintain the filter and validation rules for each field in the Model so regardless of the form I'm using the same filtering and validation rules will automatically be adopted.  I'm still relatively new to ZF2, so I'm really asking if there is another way to do this besides the options I'm going to list below.

1. Write my own `\Zend\Form\FormInterface` implementation which prevents the "copying" of the inputfilter.
2. Have a Model which only contains the fields for this particular form.
3. Re-think my DB design so that it makes sense to have a direct field to field relationship between all of my models and forms.

Much appreciation!

**Note:** I tried to pull in only the `InputInterface`'s I needed using the `\Zend\Input\InputFilter::get('FieldNameHere')` from my model object with-in the Form's Factory, but the `\Zend\Form\Form::bind()` just overwrites it.

Comment: You should look into [validation groups](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups).

Comment: @AlexP That was exactly what I needed, thank you.  If you post an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which elements should be included in the validation of the form using [validation groups](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups).

From the documentation:

> Sometimes you want to validate only a subset of form elements. As an example, let’s say we’re re-using our contact form over a web service; in this case, the Csrf, Captcha, and submit button elements are not of interest, and shouldn’t be validated.
>
> Zend\Form provides a proxy method to the underlying InputFilter‘s setValidationGroup() method, allowing us to perform this operation.

```
$form->setValidationGroup('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message');
$form->setData($data);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // Contains only the "name", "email", "subject", and "message" values
    $data = $form->getData();
}
```